# ODK aggregate doesn't start. Multiple exceptions

Tags: java, mysql, spring, odk

I want to install odk aggregate and I am facing some issues. 
I tried it on a computer and I got this:

Jun 15, 2017 8:46:11 PM org.opendatakit.common.persistence.engine.mysql.DatastoreImpl assertRelation
WARNING: Failure: _granted_authority_hierarchy exception: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar 
    [CREATE TABLE
    `odk_prod`.`_granted_authority_hierarchy` ( `_URI` VARCHAR(80) CHARACTER SET 
    utf8 NOT NULL , `_CREATOR_URI_USER` VARCHAR(80) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL ,
     `_CREATION_DATE` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL , `_LAST_UPDATE_URI_USER` VARCHAR(80) 
    CHARACTER SET utf8 NULL , `_LAST_UPDATE_DATE` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL , 
    `DOMINATI
    NG_GRANTED_AUTHORITY` VARCHAR(80) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL , 
    `SUBORDINATE_GRANTED_AUTHORITY` VARCHAR(80) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL , 
    INDEX(`_URI` )  U
    SING HASH , INDEX(`_LAST_UPDATE_DATE` ) , 
    INDEX(`DOMINATING_GRANTED_AUTHORITY` )  USING HASH  ) ];

nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

'(6) NOT NULL , `_LAST_UPDATE_URI_USER` VARCHAR(80) CHARACTER SET utf8 NULL , `_L' at line 1

I thought there was a problem with the way I install MySQL. So I tried it on an other computer and I got a different message
    org.apache.catalina.LifeCycleException: Failed to start component

If anyone had an idea it would nice.
thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps yet.

But this link can help you [Odk Aggregate v1.4.15 ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45684009/odk-aggregate-v1-4-15-ubuntu-14-04/45696228#45696228)

In my case it was a version of mysql required.

Grettings